# C# How can I set the color of text in a richtextbox?

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I have a richtextbox in an app and I'd like key words to be in another color, how can I do this?

Thanks
Jade

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can use:

```
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Yellow;
richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Blue;
```

to select a text set:

```
richTextBox1.SelectionStart = text_position_in_editor (caret position)

richTextBox1.SelectionLength = text_length
```

then set SelectionColor ... (see all properties starting with Selection...)

Or, you can set directly the `Rtf property (or richTextBox1.SelectedRtf)` which contains formatting info.

Type some text in WordPad, change it's formatting, copy and paste it into your RichTextBox, show the property Rtf value, you should be able to learn faster how to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the text added to the box in a Rich Text Markup which specifies the particular color.  Here is a link to the basics of Rich Text marker

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format

Comment: Technically this will work, but it's (usually) easier to do najmeddine's technique of working with the `Selection*` properties.

Comment: that's the hard way... for the easy way, see najmeddine's answer ;)