# How can I color text in a Rich Textbox in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, richtextbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# How can I set the color of text in a richtextbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391321/c-how-can-i-set-the-color-of-text-in-a-richtextbox)

In Visual C#.NET, I want to change the color of specific text when it is typed in to a rich text box.

For example, I might want to color the world "hi", so when the user is typing in the rich text box, if they type "hi" it would change colors and the word "hi" would be a different color from all the other text in the rich text box.

How would I do that? Is there a better way to do that, not in a rich textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your TextChanged Event handler

```
txtRichTextBox.Select(txtRichTextBox.Text.IndexOf("hi"), "hi".Length);
txtRichTextBox.SelectionColor = YourColor;
txtRichTextBox.SelectionFont = new Font("Times New Roman",FontStyle.Bold);
```

Comment: what do I put in for "youText"? And am I missing a directive or something?

Comment: Note--for this to work you must use the AppendText method. Assigning anything to the text property of the box will break it.

Answer (score 0):

I remember doing something like this in Flex.  We had to extend the richtextbox control, and make our own custom control, that would change the text color depending on what was being entered.  We used data change events to achieve this.  But my gut guess is you'll have to create a custom control to do this.

Comment: How do I create a custom control that can function like a rich text box?

Comment: @Jacob - here is a great example of a rich text box contorl, that extends the default rich text box control to detect URL highlighting in the control.  This might be your best bet to do what you want to do, as you can apply you needs.  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/RichTextBoxLinks.aspx  (although it's an older version of c#, it will get you on the right path)